# Yasnippet installing with cask in Emacs error

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I've been trying to install Yasnippet using Cask, but I can't get it to work. I've installed other packages using Cask and they seem to work, but Yasnippet won't load. I get this error when I opened Emacs and have added (yas-global-mode 1) to my init.el file.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/adam/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: Don't know how to make a localized variable an alias

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Cask has been erased and reinstalled in my home folder. The Yasnippet map in /home/adam/.emacs.d/.cask/24.3.1/elpa/ has been erased and reinstalled with Cask.

Thanks in advance for help!

Edit: emacs --debug-init

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Don't know how to make a localized variable an alias")
  defvaralias(yas/fallback-behavior yas-fallback-behavior)
  byte-code("\304\211\203?
```

Comment: Have you tried starting Emacs with --debug-init and what info does that provide?